# Intento actualizar un registro de mi bd con entity framework pero no me lo actualiza (No marca errores)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Lo que quiero hacer es una simple actualizacion de un registro de mi tabla y en este caso lo quiero hacer con linq pero al momento en el que llega a ese pedazo de codigo no me marca ninfun error y ejecuta todas las lineas pero no me actualiza el registro:

Código Actual del update:

```
   clasexxx vehiculo = (from conf in context.xxx
                                           where conf.xxx.Equals(config.xxx)
                                           select new clasexxx()
                                           {
                                               xxx = conf.xxx,
                                           }).First();
               vehiculo.Idioma = config.Idioma;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return retorno;
```

Ya puedo hacer inserciones de mi registro pero quiero que cuando el id de la escuela no se vuelva agregar sino que simplemente se actualice el que ya existe.

Answer (score 1):

Para una edición utiliza esta vía.

```
 context.Entry(vehiculo).State = EntityState.Modified;
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: me marca el siguiente error  The entity type clasexxx is not part of the model for the current context, sabe a que se pueda deber

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está enla obteción de datos con el new

Intenta esto :

```
clasexxx vehiculo = context.xxx.where(conf => conf.xxx.Equals(config.xxx)).FirstOrDefault();

               vehiculo.Idioma = config.Idioma;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return retorno;
```